# Lottery probability question...

Tags: probability

A person participates in a state lottery by selecting six numbers from 1 through 59. If the six numbers match the six drawn by the lottery, regardless of order, then the participant wins the first prize of millions of dollars. If a participant's numbers match five of the six drawn, the participant wins second prize, which is not millions of dollars.

I know that the probability of winning the first prize is .0000000222 because of 1 / (59 C 6).

How can I find the second prize winner?

Comment: Second place needs to capture exactly five of the six numbers. How many ways can this be done? The denominator remains the same: there are still $\binom{59}{6}$ ways to draw six numbers from 59. However, the numerator should count the number of ways you may draw five numbers from the winning six and one number from the remaining 53 numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Corporation must pick exactly $5$ of our numbers. Which $5$? These can be chosen in $\binom{6}{5}$ ways.

For each of these ways, there are $\binom{53}{1}$ ways for the Corporation to choose a sixth number that doesn't match  ours.

It follows that there are $\binom{6}{5}\binom{53}{1}$ different Corporation choices that give us a  second prize.

For the probability, divide by $\binom{59}{6}$.